# Is it posible to re-use a JVM that was created in another OS/400 Job from RPG?

Tags: java, jvm, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have an RPG PGM that calls a Java class, if there's no JVM in the Job, the RPG runtime adds one when the Java class is called. After this, all calls that come from the same RPG program or another RPG program that's in the same Job use the same JVM.

The thing is that if I start the same PRG program from another Job it starts another JVM, basically I have one JVM for Job.

I want to know if it's possible to have just one JVM and attach to it from other Jobs.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is how I'm trying to integrate RPG/JAVA through procedures. But for some reason, the threads are not fired.

```
========
RPG CODE
========

d DSP_class       c                   'tests.mthreads.RPGProcessDispatcher'
d DSP             s               o   class(*JAVA:DSP_class)           

d DSP_new         pr              o   extproc(*JAVA:                   
d                                     DSP_class:                       
d                                     *CONSTRUCTOR)                    

d DSP_dispatch    pr              n   extproc(*JAVA:                   
d                                     DSP_class:                       
d                                     'dispatch')                      


d dispatcher      s                   like(DSP)
d dispatched      s               n            

d i               s              3i 0          
  /free                                         
     dispatcher = DSP_new();                   
     for i=1 by 1 to 2;                        
        dispatched = DSP_dispatch(dispatcher); 
      endfor;                                   

      *inlr=*on;   
  /end-free        


RPGProcessDispatcher
====================

public boolean dispatch() {
    if (freeThreads == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    System.out.println("Tread @"+freeThreads);
    decThreadsAvailable();

    RPGSimpleProcess p = new RPGSimpleProcess();
    p.registerRunCompleted(this);

    Thread t = new Thread(p);
    t.start();

    return true;
}

RPGSimpleProcess
================

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100000);

        notifyEnd();        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without more information; e.g. how does the "RPG PGM" launch the JVM, and how does it communicate with it?

Answer (score 7):

The quick answer is no.

The longer answer is that if you had a never ending server job running that accepted requests from the individual clients, then all the clients would in effect be reusing the JVM started by the server job.

One way to create this server job is to use data queues to pass data from the client to the server job, and back.  Start the server job when the machine IPLs (add an autostart job entry to a batch subsystem) and have it listen to a data queue via [QRCVDTAQ](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qrcvdtaq.htm).  That job will start the JVM, call the Java methods and return the answer back via [QSNDDTAQ](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qsnddtaq.htm).  Each client would do the same thing, giving two-way communication between hundreds of individual jobs and a single server job.

Comment: Thanks Buck, I've actually been working on that exact schema. The server job is an RPGLE that reads form de DTAQ and calls to a Java Class though Procedures, the Java Class fires a thread. But I getting some error about a file and multi-threads, but I'm not opening any files.

Comment: If I do the same thing, but instead of calling the Java Class trough a Procedure, I call a CLP PGM and fire a RUNJVA command that runs a Main Java Class that fires multiple threads, then the code works. But the "threads" have all different job numbers, I'm lost.

Comment: CPF4380: Open attributes not valid in a multithreaded job. But right now I'm thinking it has something to do with debugging. When I run normally, it doesn't fire the thread, and I don't get any message.

Comment: CPF4380 lists the file and library in the second level help text.  That might give you an idea what file the code is trying to open.  In the RPG H-specification, do you have THREAD(*SERIALIZE) or *CONCURRENT specified?  Or, in the case of the RUNJVA version, why is it important that the threads all have the same job number?

Comment: In the case of RUNJVA, if they have all different job numbers it means they all have different JVM. I want them to be under the same JVM.

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question with some specific code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just did a test and all my Java threads are in the same IBM i job.  I suspect that there's something you are doing that is starting multiple jobs on the IBM side.  Are you using any JT400 classes?  JDBC?  Anything at all that communicates between Java and the IBM i?

Comment: Just for the record: It is possible to code the whole data queue scenario in pure Java.